# allowLargeResults in BigQuery not working

Tags: python, google-bigquery

When I execute this piece of Python code:

```
body = {
  'configuration': {
    'query': {
      'destinationTable': {
        'projectId': PROJECT_ID,
        'tableId': 'new_items',
        'datasetId': 'data_set'
      },
      'writeDisposition': 'WRITE_TRUNCATE',
      'allowLargeResults': True,
      'query': 'select item from data_set.items where item not in (select item from data_set.old_items);'
    }
  }
} 
job = service.jobs().insert(projectId = PROJECT_ID, body = body).execute()
```

Despite having `allowLargeResults` set to True, I get this error:

> Response too large to return. Consider setting allowLargeResults to true in your job configuration.

Can anybody explain the reason for this and give me a hint as to how to get rid of this error?

Comment: May you please modify your question to define `service`

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that this error is due to one of the intermediate stages of the query producing results. Most probably it is the SELECT used in the NOT IN semijoin. The only workaround I can think of is to rewrite the query as

```
select a.item from 
  data_set.items a 
    left outer join each 
  data_set.old_items b
on a.item = b.item 
where b.item IS NULL
```

The NOT IN semijoin clause doesn't allow EACH modifier, but LEFT OUTER JOIN does allow it, and this should make the query scale.

Comment: Thanks, your solution works (though a little correction of your query is necessary), but I still don't know why the allowLargeResults option does not work as it is supposed to. Anyway, it is much better to run compact queries like the one you've proposed.

Comment: allowLargeResults applies to the final result of the query, but it doesn't help if some intermediate stage results get too large. That's where EACH modifier helps.